# In which Spider-Man comic does a kid gets shot while trying to save Spidey?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, spider-man

I saw a page once from this comic in which a kid gets shot while trying to save Spidey, and Peter feels responsible for it. I don't know what comic issue it was but it had all the feels and I really want to read the whole story.

Which comic was this?

Comment: Someone posted the pages of this on Facebook just now so I'm gonna see if I can track it down that way.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across the same story just now on Facebook, and after having my feels crushed, I quickly searched and found that it's apparently "What Would Spider-Man Do?", an eight-page story from *Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #700.5*. I don't know why ".5", but *#700* is the issue in which

> Peter Parker dies, and Otto Octavius becomes the Superior Spider-Man.

---

The comic opens with Spider-Man rushing the kid to hospital after he was shot in the back.

[image]

That night, Peter confides to Mary-Jane that the kid was shot while trying to save Spidey from some bank robbers, and that he feels responsible for allowing the kid to get in harm's way.

[image]
[image]

I won't post the rest of the comic here: I feel like this is enough for you to identify that it's the right one, and the rest can easily be found on Google (it's in the first page of results for "What Would Spider-Man Do?". Warning, though: you were right. This story has all the feels.